# Finding Specific Id Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have 2 Items `{"id":23,"Item":BALLPEN} , {"id":18,"Item":LAPTOP}` my problem is how to get single object? when i clicked the button I can get the Id when i'm using `console.log(this.router.snapshot.params.Id); i get specific`Id` my question is how to get a single object so i can populate it to my form?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhVjY.png)

> Routing

```
{path: 'edit/:Id', component:Component},
```

> list component .HTML

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <button mat-icon-button routerLink="/edit/{{element.id}}"
            matTooltip="Click to edit this data">
      <mat-icon class="edit-icon">edit</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

> Edit Component

```
constructor(private router:ActivatedRoute){}

    console.log(this.router.snapshot.params.Id);
        this.micro.getAllList(this.router.snapshot.params.Id).subscribe((result)=>{
         console.log(result))
        })
```

> Services

```
_URL ="https://localhost:44350/api/myList/list?";

    getAllList(id:number){
      return this.http.get(`${this._URL}/${id}`);
    }
```

Comment: can you create a stackblitz of following issue?

Comment: as you can see, i post a picture. once i clicked the edit button it gives me a id of 18, but it once i console.log, it gives me the 2 items which is 0 and 1, i want it just specific only like if id 18, all value contains in id 18 will i get

 this.micro.getAllList(this.router.snapshot.params.Id).subscribe((result)=>{
         console.log(result))
        })
here's where i tried to console it

Comment: I don't think this is an Angular issue, it is more likely due to your backend API. `Id` is unique, so suppose it should return a (single) object. You need to debug and revise the backend API to return an object, but not a list.

Comment: do you have any reference for that i'm using Entity Framework .net

Comment: Would be great if you can share the sample API action. I believe that you are using .NET / .NET Core framework for the API as you mention the Entity Framework.

Comment: private IQueryable<itemsDTO> QueryToDTO(IQueryable<ITEMS> query)
        {
            return query.Select(x => new ItemsDTO
            {

----------------------------


[HttpGet("list")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<itemDTO>> List([FromQuery] itemDTO filter, [FromQuery] PageConfig config)
        {

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are not binding your ID correctly, currently you are passing edit/{{element.id}} as string, you should use property binding to get the value, you can read more [here](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#types-of-data-binding)

your button should look like this

```
<button mat-icon-button [routerLink]="'/edit/'+element.id"
        matTooltip="Click to edit this data">
```

Comment: got a error parse error: unexpected token

Comment: `[routerLink]="'/edit/'+element.id"`, when we use binding `[property]="what-ever"` we not use inpterpolate `{{``}}` inside the quotes